# Constructor instance variable Pharo

Tags: constructor, refactoring, instance-variables, pharo

I am new to Pharo and I was wondering if there is some automatic refactoring method to create a constructor with one parameter per instance variable. Right now to do that I a create class side method that create a new instance of the class and call on the new instance a method that initialize the instance variables. It is quite boring and long, but I couldn't find a way to do it automatically (like instead I can do it for creating accessors to instance variable etc).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, it is possible.

Long answer: are you shire you want to do that? I mean usually you create an instance and set it's variables e.g:

```
window := Window new
  width: 500;
  height: 300;
  x: 5;
  y: 10;
  yourself.
```

and you can create a getter and setter (in Nautilus) for instance variables from method's context menu or by using shortcuts.

So you can look how they are implemented and write similar thing for "constructors", but it's not a common practice in Pharo, so think twice before going this way.

Comment: ok but why is that better than:

`Windows initializeWithWidth: 500 height:300 x:5 y:10.` ? 

I your short answer you say it is possible, but can you tell me how?

oh and if I can Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: @user1544128 because you don't win a lot by doing your way. Maybe you have default values and maybe you don't have all the data at the moment of initialisation. The thing is that you have to be sure that it's used really a lot + I'd avoid a methods with long names. I'll try to expand my answer soon

Comment: Sometimes initialization methods like your #initializeWithWidth:height:x:y: are useful. For example, when the instance variables are not meant to be changed (immutable objects). I don't know of any refactoring to do that.

Still, when prototyping your application, you might want to avoid this practice. I used to have plenty of initialization methods like this one but I stopped because it was too much work to maintain (e.g., when instance variables are added/removed).

Comment: @DamienCassou yes, but usually I find them tailored by the method's ideas. I don't know if it just makes sense to generate everything, and then question is it which order. But muse there can be a smart generator.